# ¿ Se puede agregar un elemento dentro de la etiqueta <title> </title> con un append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Deseo agregar los estilos css que lleva una aplicación con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), lo he intentado de la siguiente manera pero no he logrado que funcione:

```
// Llamó los al "<links/>" al index, por medio de una funcion que tengo establecida en un 
// documento js
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var inicio = new Index();
            inicio.cssLib();
        });
    </script>
```

**js**

```
function Index(){

 this.cssLib = function(){   
    // he intentado hacerlo con un after y aca con un append pero no he tenido 
    // éxito
    // (no estoy seguro que el append funcione de esta forma, pero quise intentarlo)
    $('title').append(function(){
        $(this).load("assets/links/cssLinks.html");
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí se pueden agregar, tanto con [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) como con [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), 
hice una prueba rápida con `$.ajax()`, puesto que `.load()` no es más que una forma rápida de llamar este método:

```
$.ajax('assets/links/cssLinks.html')
  .done(function(data){
    $('title').append(data);
  })
```

Comment: Lo hice de esta manera, tomando el ejemplo que compartiste y funciono `$('head').load('assets/links/cssLinks.html', function(data){$(this).append(data);}); `  muchas gracias

Comment: Sería bueno conocer el motivo del voto negativo.

Comment: ni idea amigo, la verdad no se porque lo hicieron en realidad la respuesta es acertada, por eso la elegí como respuesta y le di voto positivo. :O

Comment: @Shaz, ¿es `title` o `tittle`?

Comment: Según la pregunta (el título y el contenido de la misma), es `tittle`, sé que no es un tag válido html y que necesitaría un componente o similar, pero funciona la respuesta.